# What is the Probability of someone meeting a person they know on a train?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, recreational-mathematics, conditional-probability

My friends and I had a question to calculate the probability of meeting someone you know on the train. So we created a mathematical model question as follows:

> A man *'A'* travels from a place X to Y. There are three trains $T_1$,$T_2$ and $T_3$, of 9 seats each, which connect X and Y. A total of 27 people use the Trains to go from X to Y, these 27 people include our man *'A'*, the 4 people he knows ($B_1$,$B_2$,$B_2$ and $B_4$), and remaining 22 strangers to *'A'* ($C_1$,$C_2$,... to $C_{22}$). The man *'A'* meets only 3 people from the train he is in, during the journey, after which he doesn't meet anyone else. What is the probability that he had met at least one person that he knew?

so we had a few attempts at solving the question *(listed below)*, and the solutions are all different approaches and give quite different final answers; it would be great if I could know which of the three solutions is correct, or if none are - then how I should go about the problem. Thanks!

Solution [1]:(Friend 1?)

> In a general sense, let *$p_k$* be the number of people *'A'* knows, and *$p_t$* be the total number of people using the Trains (not including *'A'*), and *p* be the number of people *'A'* meets. Then:
>
> > Probability of *'A'* knowing a person he meets is *$$ = (\frac{p_k}{p_t})$$*
> > Probability of *'A'* not knowing a person he meets is *$$ = (1 - \frac{p_k}{p_t})$$*
> > Probability of *'A'* not knowing the first *p* people he meets is *$$ = (1 - \frac{p_k}{p_t})^p$$*
> > Probability of *'A'* knowing at least one the first *p* people he meets is *$$ = 1 - (1 - \frac{p_k}{p_t})^p$$*
> > So in our case, *$p_k$* = 4, *$p_t$* = 26 (27 - 1 as it doesn't include *'A'*), *p* = 3, and substitutution gives approximately Probability = 0.3942.

Solution [2]:(Friend 2?)

> In a general sense, let *$p_{dk}$* be the number of people *'A'* **doesn't** know, and *$p_t$* be the total number of people using the Trains (not including *'A'*), and *p* be the number of people *'A'* meets. Then:
>
> > Probability of *'A'* not knowing a person he meets is *$$ = (\frac{p_{dk}}{p_t})$$*
> > Probability of *'A'* not knowing even the second person he meets after the first is *$$ = (\frac{p_{dk}}{p_t})(\frac{p_{dk}-1}{p_t-1})$$*
> > Probability of *'A'* not knowing even the $p^{th}$ person he meets is *$$ = (\frac{p_{dk}}{p_t})(\frac{p_{dk}-1}{p_t-1})...(\frac{p_{dk}-p+1}{p_t-p+1})$$*
> > Probability of *'A'* knowing a person he meets is *$$ = 1 - (\frac{p_{dk}}{p_t})(\frac{p_{dk}-1}{p_t-1})...(\frac{p_{dk}-p+1}{p_t-p+1})$$*
> > So in our case, *$p_{dk}$* = 26 - 4 = 22, *$p_t$* = 26 (27 - 1 as it doesn't include *'A'*), *p* = 3, and substitutution gives approximately Probability = 0.4077

Solution [3]:(This one's mine! But uses *P&C* :/)

> 1. taking all possible cases into account (Cases 1 to 5 as denoted under point 2)
>
> > $N_{all}$ = $N_1 + N_2 + N_3 + N_4 + N_5$
> > (Where $N_1$ to $N_5$ are as denoted under point 2 for each case respectively)

> 2. Let *'A'* be on any one train, the remaining 8 members can show a demographic as:
>
> > - Case 1: All 4 people ($B_1$,$B_2$,$B_2$ and $B_4$) that *'A'* knows are on the same train, this can happen in $N_1$ ways. $N_1$ = $\binom{4}{4}\binom{22}{4}$
> > - Case 2: some 3 of $B_1$,$B_2$,$B_2$ and $B_4$ are on the same train, this can happen in $N_2$ ways. $N_2$ = $\binom{4}{3}\binom{22}{5}$
> > - Case 3: some 2 of $B_1$,$B_2$,$B_2$ and $B_4$ are on the same train, this can happen in $N_3$ ways. $N_3$ = $\binom{4}{2}\binom{22}{6}$
> > - Case 4: some 1 of $B_1$,$B_2$,$B_2$ and $B_4$ is on the same train, this can happen in $N_4$ ways. $N_4$ = $\binom{4}{1}\binom{22}{7}$
> > - Case 5: None of $B_1$,$B_2$,$B_2$ and $B_4$ are on the same train, this can happen in $N_5$ ways. $N_5$ = $\binom{4}{0}\binom{22}{8}$

> 3. The probability of A meeting someone he knows out of the three people he meets in each case would be as follows:
>
> > - Case 1: $P_1$ = $\frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{4}{2} + \binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{1} + \binom{4}{3}\binom{4}{0}}{\binom{8}{3}}$
> > - Case 2: $P_2$ = $\frac{\binom{3}{1}\binom{5}{2} + \binom{3}{2}\binom{5}{1} + \binom{3}{3}\binom{5}{0}}{\binom{8}{3}}$
> > - Case 3: $P_3$ = $\frac{\binom{2}{1}\binom{6}{2} + \binom{2}{2}\binom{6}{1}}{\binom{8}{3}}$
> > - Case 4: $P_4$ = $\frac{\binom{1}{1}\binom{7}{2}}{\binom{8}{3}}$
> > - Case 5: $P_5$ = 0 (since there is no person that A knows on the train)

> 4. Final expression for the probability would be
>
> > $$Probability (P) = \frac{N_1P_1 + N_2P_2 + N_3P_3 + N_4P_4 + N_5P_5}{N_{all}}$$
> > which on evaluation comes upto Probability(P) = 0.4096

Any Help would be highly appreciated! Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: @markvs, Perhaps it's an overnight commuter express (like a hotel-themed one)? A very tangential but still intriguing question.

Comment: @okzoomer But please do tell me what modification you'd have made to my solution so I can understand the mistake I've made. Thanks!

Comment: @Aryaan i answered below. Your $P$s were correct; but I just simplified them using the complement probability to reduce chances of error when punching into the calculator.

Comment: @okzoomer ah thankyou this had been bugging me the whole day!! I've now come to realize 0.4096 was a product of a calculation error (more like an entry error as you rightfully mentioned) than an error of approach! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, notice that the size of the train doesn't matter - it only matters that he meets 3 people. I would approach the problem as, "How many arrangements of 26 objects are there, where first you choose 3 objects (in order) from a subset of 22 of those objects, then order the remaining 23 objects freely", divided by the number of arrangements of 26 objects. There are ${}^{22}P_3$ ways to choose the people sitting next to you if you don't know them, and once you remove those people, there are $23!$ ways to arrange the people not sitting next to you. So there are ${}^{22}P_3 \times 23!$ ways to arrange everyone so you're not sitting next to someone you know, out of $26!$ ways total, i.e. the probability you don't sit next to someone you know is
\begin{align}
\frac{{}^{22}P_3 \times 23!}{26!}=\frac{{}^{22}P_3}{{}^{26}P_3}\approx 0.5923,
\end{align}
and the probability you do sit next to someone you know is 0.4077. So your second friend is right.

Your first friend forgot that the probabilities aren't independent. If you don't know the person on your left, there are fewer other people you don't know available, so that increases the chances you know the person on your right.

I like counting permutations instead of combinations because I find it's easy to count different things in different places when I use combinations. In your case, your $N_{all}$ is the number of ways to choose people on the first or second train (including yourself, which isn't what I would normally do - I would normally label whichever train I was on as "Train 1"), but your $N_1$ to $N_5$ are only the number of ways to choose people on the *same train as you*. I suspect that if you replace your $N_{all}$ with $\binom{26}{8}$, you would get the right answer.

Comment: OH HA! I understood why I've got to change N(all) to N1+N2..+N5 (that makes it C(26,8) instead, and I've tried to resubstitute the numbers and I've gotten 0.4096, which unless if I'd made a silly calculation error or my solution skips some small number of cases, seems awfully close to my 2nd friends answer or 0.4077. Thank you! Though it still isn't clear to me why the number of trains or the number os seats didn't matter...

Comment: Yes I confirmed OP's approach works with $N_\text{all} = \binom{26}{8}$

Answer (score 0):

Friend One is wrong since the probability changes with each person.

---

Here's OP's approach updated using the complement. The $P_k$ values should be the same.

$$P_1 = 1 - \frac{\binom{4}{3}}{\binom{8}{3}} = \frac{13}{14}$$
$$P_2 = 1 - \frac{\binom{5}{3}}{\binom{8}{3}} = \frac{23}{28}$$
$$P_3 = 1 - \frac{\binom{6}{3}}{\binom{8}{3}} = \frac{9}{14}$$
$$P_4 = 1 - \frac{\binom{7}{3}}{\binom{8}{3}} = \frac{3}{8} $$
$$P_5 = 0$$

Using instead $$N_\text{all} = \binom{26}{8}$$ and keeping OP's $N$ values, we have

$$P=  \frac{N_1P_1 + N_2P_2 + N_3P_3 + N_4P_4 + N_5P_5}{N_\text{all}} \approx 0.4077$$

---

The number of trains didn't matter because each train multiplied the number of outcomes by $3$, but at the the same time only $\frac{1}{3}$ of the new outcomes are favorable, i.e. $P = \frac{3P}{3}$. Not that any of your or our solutions considered the other two trains; we just considered the train man $A$ was on.

It also does't matter whether you randomly choose a group of eight, then choose a group three, or just choose a group of three directly. This updated solution of yours just shows that. Consider just choosing one person instead of three. $\frac{1}{27}$ is chance of picking a certain person directly. For first choosing a group of eight then the person, we have $\frac{8}{27}\frac{1}{8} + \frac{19}{27}\frac{0}{19}$, meaning there is $\frac{1}{8}$ chance of choosing the person when the person is in the group, and $0$ chance when the person is not. The "$8$" cancels in the first product and second product is $0$, so this is also $\frac{1}{27}$.

This is analogous to having the same probability of obtaining a poker hand whether you draw the cards one at a time, or all at the same time. If all the objects are distinct, then permutation and combination for such group-making problems yield the same answer, because each combination can be obtained through an equal number of permutations. In summary, if all items are distinct, a combination problem can be solved via permutation, as 1Rock has done.